# Generating coordinates with attributes from a georeferenced map

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I've got a (physical) hydrographic map that I'm intending to scan and georeference into QGIS. On this map are hundreds of point depths measurements and what I want is to obtain an  array with the coordinates and depth for each point.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this in QGIS or ArcGIS (e.g. clicking on a point to copy the coordinates into an attribute table where I can manually enter the depth for that point)?

Comment: Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour].

Comment: Yes, this can be done in QGIS. Question answered =P so, besides the missing focus on which software you want to use, you need to focus on specific parts of the task which you tried solving but couldn't get right (incl. idea, research, what you tried, etc).